# Is there a way I can auto fill an input form based on a selectbox drop down?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to auto fill an input form based on the selection of a selectbox.
the auto fill text comes from my database

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="kode_part" class="control-label">Kode Part <span><small class="text-danger">*This field is required</small></span></label>
<select class="form-control kode_part" name="kode_part" id="kode_part" required>
<?php if(count($tabel_part)){ ?>
<option></option>
<?php foreach ($tabel_part as $list){ ?>
<option data-info="<?php echo $list['kode_part'] ?>">
<?php echo $list['kode_part']; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
```

text auto fill based on selection:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="nama_part" class="control-label">Nama Part*</label>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="nama_part" name="nama_part" />
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#kode_part').change(function(){
$('#nama_part').val( $(this).find('list:selected').data('nama_part') ); 
});
});
</script>
```

i've try that but nothing happens in my view.
Any help you can give I appreciate it

Comment: why there is a `list` before `:selected`?

Comment: both html is in same page?

Comment: yes, there are in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#kode_part').on('change', function() {
  //you can use this too
  $('#nama_part').val( $('#kode_part').find(":selected").text());  
});
```

Comment: nothing happens too, is there any wrong in my form?

Comment: Did you check your console portion, is there any syntax error?

Comment: yes, there's an error, referse to my controller: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list,
how can i fix this?

Comment: public function add_data()
 {
        $this->load->model('model_tabel_material');
        $data['tabel_part'] = $this->model_tabel_material->get_kode_part();
        $data['tabel_part'] = $this->model_tabel_material->get_nama_part();
        $data['tabel_customer'] = $this->model_tabel_material->get_nama_customer();
  $this->load->view('datamaster/tabel_material/v_add_material', $data);
 }

Comment: @BataraSitohang, it's all ok now, he did a syntax mistake, I've fix it, try it one more time (copy-past).

Comment: yeah, it's working nicely...
in my template, i want to change the view..
example: Q12HLC-GCFRVYBK01 - COVER FRONT KVY
Q12HLC-GCFRVYBK01 is #kode_part
COVER FRONT KVY is #nama_part

right now both of the id appears, so i need only one id (#nama_part) appear in my template, 
what should i do, which code should i change or add?
thank you very much

Comment: your welcome, if its work form you then kindly upvote and accept the answer

Comment: And if you have another issue with this scenario then please open a new post so everyone can answer you